# Using JQuery to replace text in HTML but ignoring certain HTML id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, handlebars.js

So I'm currently using Handlebars to grab data from a JSON file to show its data on the screen. Right now it's looking similar to this:

```
<div class="content" id = "topic">
  {{#each topics}}
     <a href="{{topic}}" id = "ignore">
         <h2>{{topic}}</h2>
     </a>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

I want to replace specific characters within the word topic with another one, for example if the {{topic}} was "Hi%3F" I want to replace the "%3F" part with a '?' everywhere except the part with id="ignore". The replace function I'm using right now is:

```
$("#topic").html($("#topic").html().replace(/%3F/g,'?'));
```

this manages to replace everything so far, but I'm not sure how to get it to ignore the tags with the id="ignore". There's probably an easier way to make the link portion work like its supposed to but this is what I have gotten now and I don't want to mess around or change too much.

Thanks!

Comment: "_tags with the id="ignore"_" doesn't sound right, `id`s should be unique within a document.

Comment: @Edward what Teemu said is correct! you don't want to have the same id's for every link. You may want to use a class instead

Comment: Hmm will that make a difference though? I guess to put it in different terms I want to run my jquery script on the div with the id="topic" (sorry before it said title and that was a typo) but ignore the <a> tag with the id="ignore" if that makes sense.

Comment: @EdwardTo  looks like you are doing a loop and assigning the same id = 'ignore' to each link and that is wrong. You CANNOT have the same id for each link. You're html still doesn't make any sense

Comment: Oh ok. Any advice on what to do then? Other than changing it to class?

Answer (score 0):

Is not legal html to duplicate Ids.  Ids need to be unique. I'd suggest adding a `class="unique"` to your anchor tag and use

```
<div class="content" id = "topic">
     <a href="Hi%3F" class = "topic">
       <h2>Hi%3F</h2>
     </a>
     <a href="Hi%3F" class = "topic ignore">
       <h2>Hi%3F</h2>
     </a>
     <a href="Hi%3F" class = "topic">
       <h2>Hi%3F</h2>
     </a>
     <a href="Hi%3F" class = "topic ignore">
       <h2>Hi%3F</h2>
     </a>
</div>

<script>
    $("a.topic").not(".ignore").each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/%3F/g,'?'));
    });
</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/huquyufafe/edit?html,output

Comment: And you have no text within your anchor tags. It looks like its closing tag should really be below `<h2>{{topic}}</h2>`

Comment: Hmm for some reason it's not working... I changed the id to class="unique" but the URL still ends up having a '?' in it.

Comment: @K Scandrett oh sorry that was another typo. I'll change it. Thanks!

Comment: OH WAIT I GOT IT! I switched it around and added a "class=topic" inside of the h2's so instead of ignoring I just found the specific ones with the class to change that.